# Correct way to show filestructure in const = require?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filesystems, discord, discord.js

I'm having an issue with my `const errors = require("./utils/errors.js");`. I have several files that reference the `errors.js` file, yet due to the nature of the file structure (`commands/mod/ban.js`) it seems as though it can't find `errors.js`. The specific error I'm getting is `throw err  Error: Cannot find module './utils/errors.js'` If I had to guess, the files that cannot see `error.js` are only viewing a single file above their own. How do I make it so they can find `const errors = require("./utils/errors.js");`?

Comment: `const errors = require("../utils/errors.js");` will go up a folder first, then go into the `utils` folder.

Comment: See my comment below.

Comment: Based on the file structure you need `const errors = require("../../utils/errors.js");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `..` to go up a folder. Based on what you've told us about your filesystem, this should work:

```
const errors = require("../../utils/errors.js");
```

Comment: I've tried that, yet I get the same error. Which makes no sense because what you've posted makes perfect sense.

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of the filesystem (in relation to your main file containing the above code, and `errors.js`)?

Comment: [Here is a screenshot of my file structure. Ignore the nsfw stuff.](https://snag.gy/d0ZNmP.jpg)

Comment: it may be of note that instead of it being `commands/mod/ban.js` it is actually `app/commands/mod/ban.js`

Comment: So the above file is `app/commands/mod/ban.js`, and you want `app/utils/errors.js`?

Comment: That is correct. I see nothing wrong with the answer you posted. Maybe its just Glitch "glitching" and deciding it doesn't want to play nice with the file system?

Comment: OK, I see the problem - you need to go up another folder. Currently my code is looking for `utils/errors.js` inside `commands`.

Comment: Ah! That seems to have fixed it. Such a simple solution to such a frustrating problem. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @Koto, always glad to help.